# Usage of exact prop with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a private route as follows.

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const { component: Component, path } = props;
  const isAuthenticated = true;

  return (
    <Route
      // exact (1)
      path={path}
      render={() => (
        isAuthenticated
          ? (
            <Component />
          )
          : (
            <Redirect
              to="/"
            />
          ))}
    />
  );
};
```

I am implementing in the app js file as follows.

```
 <Router>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoutes
          // exact (2)
          path="/users"
          component={Users}
        />
        <PrivateRoutes
          // exact (3)
          path="/users/add"
          component={AddUser}
        />
      </Switch>
 </Router>
```

I noticed the following behaviors based on me commenting off the ***exact*** keyword in location (1),(2),(3)

- When 1,2,3 are commented the AddUser component is viewable when i go to */users/add*
- When only 2,3 are commented the AddUser component gives a blank white screen when i go to */users/add*
- When only 1 is commented the AddUser component is viewable when i go to */users/add*
- When 1,2,3 are **not** commented the AddUser component is viewable when i go to */users/add*

I thought we only have to pass the exact keyword to the Route Component which we import from react-router.How ever in one of the above cases not putting ***exact*** on  causes the AddUsers component to not render.

What is the reason for this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

React-router matches the first route, so you need to sort your routes components by the most complex at the top, something like:

- /very/complex/route
- /very/complex
- /very

The problem you have in your code is that you don't pass the `...rest` props of the  component to your  component. It should be something like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
 return (
   <Route
     {...rest}
     render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
        />
       )
     }
   />
  )
```

Notice that the `...rest` contains the "exact" prop that is defined in your , so that you don't have to define it twice - once in the PrivateRoute and once in the Route.
So when you specify it in 1 and not in 2,3 it doesn't matter, but the opposite does because "exact" is a prop of 
Hope this helps!